# why flutter test coverage does not cover assert statements?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I have a constructor for LoginPageBloc as shown below

```
 LoginPageBloc(
  {@required this.dataRepository,
 })
  : assert(null != dataRepository);
```

when I use flutter test --coverage, the assertion statements are excluded. why??

Then I checked on the dart-lang repo for any open issues, and I found [this](https://github.com/dart-lang/coverage/issues/251).

[This](https://coveralls.io/builds/22463149/source?filename=lib/src/cupertino/date_picker.dart#L179) coverall result also shows the same issue (found in that git repo issue).

But, that issue status is closed and I found the following message thereby @ZichangG.

> VM uses function calls to determine. Callsites that have been executed will be considered as a hit.
>
> If a variable is evaluated, like assert(mode == null), an implicit
>   getter function will be called if it is not a local variable. For this
>   case assert(callback != null), callback is a local variable and it is
>   also not being called here.
>
> When functions that has been executed are evaluated, we set the first
>   token position of that function as a hit. That's probably the reason
>   why a line like assert( () { will be marked as hit. Because the
>   closure function starts in this line.

I having difficulty understanding the above message by @ZichangG.

Unfortunately, I am still experiencing the same problem. 
Just because of these assertion statements, I am unable to reach 100% code coverage.

**why flutter test coverage does not cover assert statements?**

**Could you please explain to me the reason behind this and what should I do to avoid this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap the assert call into a until function to by pass the issue.

See below,

**Define a util function**

```
  void assertNotNull(Object object) {
    assert(object != null);
    }
```

**Use it like**

```
 assertNotNull(dataRepository);
```

Comment: Then the `assert` function is in `assertNotNull` is not covered :D .